# ZipInputStream cannot parse a 281 TB zip bomb

Tags: java

I have this simple Groovy script that lists entries in a zip files alongside their uncompressed file size

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Files

@CompileStatic
long zipSize(InputStream is) {
    long totalSize = 0
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000]
    new ZipInputStream(is).withCloseable { zis ->
        while(true) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.nextEntry
            if(zipEntry == null) break
            long entrySize = 0
            while(true) {
                int read = zis.read(buffer)
                if(read <= 0) break
                totalSize += read
                entrySize += read
            }
            zis.closeEntry()
            println("Uncompressed size of ${zipEntry.name} is ${entrySize} bytes")
        }
    }
    return totalSize
}

args.each {
    println("Opening '$it'")
    Path path = Path.of(it)
    long size = zipSize(Files.newInputStream(path))
    println("Total uncompressed size of '$it' is $size bytes")
}
```

I tried running it with zblg.zip which is a zip bomb downloaded from [here](https://www.bamsoftware.com/hacks/zipbomb/), the file is supposed to contain several thousands of entries, each one being about 4GB in size, however the output of the script is simply:

```
Opening 'Downloads/zblg.zip'
Uncompressed size of 0 is 4294967240 bytes
Total uncompressed size of 'Downloads/zblg.zip' is 4294967240 bytes
```

meaning that only the first entry is read, the program doesn't show any error neither throws any exception, it simply acts as if the zip archive only contained a single entry... Is there any limitation of `ZipInputStream` I am not aware of or I cannot find in the documentation?

EDIT:

I've put together a Java 8 example as well to reproduce the issue

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;


public class zipSize {
    private static long zipSize(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        long totalSize = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        try(ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is)) {
            while(true) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
                if(zipEntry == null) break;
                long entrySize = 0;
                while(true) {
                    int read = zis.read(buffer);
                    if(read <= 0) break;
                    entrySize += read;
                }
                totalSize += entrySize;
                zis.closeEntry();
                System.out.printf("Uncompressed size of '%s' is %d bytes\n", zipEntry.getName(), entrySize);
            }
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for(String arg : args) {
            System.out.printf("Opening '%s'\n", arg);
            Path path = Paths.get(arg);
            long size = zipSize(Files.newInputStream(path));
            System.out.printf("Total uncompressed size of '%s' is %d bytes\n", arg, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner while loop one could comment out for the moment, and simply use `zipEntry.getSize()`.

Comment: ok, fair.. but that doesn't make any difference in terms of the actual result

Comment: Instead of phyically reading the blocks, just skipping to the next ZipEntry should almost work, given correct compressed sizes.

Comment: I tried that and haven't noticed any difference unfortunately

Comment: no, sorry.. I misread your comment, you mean skipping the part when reading the entry size altogether, right?

Comment: I've tried to only list the entry names without even trying to either read them or read their size, but still no luck, I can only read the first one

Comment: That probably means that the compressed size from the zip entry is used to "find" the next zip entry i.o. assuming it comes physically next. Or such.

Comment: I think zip files have a sort of table of content at the end, so that you don't have to actually scan through the whole file to just list the content, so the size of a particuar entry shouldn't be that relevant (but I'm not 100% sure about this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Zip file contains a sort of table of content with the list of all of its entries, named "central directory", at the end of the archive.

The problem is that `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`, being a stream, cannot read it until his duties have been already carried out.

To work around the issue, it looks for the local file header, a piece of metadata starting with the magic 0x04034b50 number (source [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/920e70701da9699765c993e11feba3cc0fd0362c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.java#L284)) that precedes every entry of the zip and it is built on the assumption that after each zip entry data, there is immediately a new local file header; if that is not the case, `ZipInputstream.getNextEntry()` returns a null entry, which is the way it normally signals that all entries have been read.

Unfortunately it is allowed to have meaningless data between one entry and the next, or even entries that aren't part of the archive anymore. This last case was actually very common in the past when zip files used to be written on several floppy disks and the physical removal of an entry at the beginning of the archive would have required to re-insert all the disks one by one to shift the following entries and shrink the archive. As this was clearly unpractical, the optimization was to simply remove the entry from the central directory at the end of the file, leaving the local file header and the actual entry content in place.

As a result of this, `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` is unreliable, as it can lead to misleading result (ghost entries and/or missing archive entries), however none of these issues happens if you can safely assume the zip file was created by the java standard library itself using [java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html), as that doesn't leave empty space between entries and only writes real (that also appears in the central directory) entries.

For this reason Zip files are generally inadequate for streaming applications as the only reliable way to read them, is to read the central directory at the end of the file first (which is what `java.util.zip.ZipFile` does and, as such, is not affected by this issue).

Further information [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html)

Comment: however, skipping entries (which is what I've experienced here) isn't listed on that page between the possible symptoms